# Modal logic for absoluteness

Tags: metaphysics, modal-logic, existence, relativism, being

Modern modal logic has the modalities of necessity and possibility. However, both of these can be seen as relative to the set of possible worlds and the accessibility relation chosen for the semantics. Similarly, the concept of "actuality" is often talked about as if it is a choice to designate or regard a certain possible world as actual. Thus, as far as the logic is concerned we could evaluate propositions relative to the assumption that some other world was actual.

It seems to me there should be a third modality of absoluteness which means that propositions are evaluated in the frame of reality *tout court*. This is distinct from necessity since a proposition can be absolutely contingently true (i.e., it is this way *tout court*, but it could have been otherwise), and relatively necessarily true (i.e., P is necessary relative to a given world and an accessibility relation).

Have any contemporary analytic philosophers or logicians explored this idea?

Comment: In modal logic with PW semantics interpreted either in Lewis's realism or Kripke's formalism, according to your current understanding, P is always *relatively* necessary relative to a given world with its own accessibility relations. Certainly you can give the "actual" world a special ontic status to introduce another "modality", but in Lewis's PW realism this has to be rejected since there's no such presumptuous ontology. It may not be clear your motivation here, maybe add a concrete example to stress the need of such "modality" can clarify your own question...

Comment: I agree that in Lewis and Kripke modal logic all necessity is relative. I am asking whether anybody has attempted to develop a modal logic which incorporates absoluteness/relativity as distinct modalities that interact logically with necessity/possibility.

Comment: Modal logic in nature braces possible worlds in order to leave aside *this* world temporarily at least and in this sense it seems contra to its spirit to single out a special "actual" world. Lewis had the idea "“absolutely every way that a world could possibly be is a way that some world is", the closest ref I can think of about "absolute modality" is Mallozzi's [What Is Absolute Modality?](https://philarchive.org/archive/MALWIA-8) for your interest...

Comment: As the referenced author hinted, the root confusion lies in the common *relativization strategy* to understand your *metaphysical* necessity in lieu of *logical* necessity, you possibly need to ask yourself is this distinction of the necessity modality absolutely necessary?...

Comment: @DoubleKnot Thank you for the reference to Mallozzi's paper. I will read it. 

To answer your question. I don't regard absoluteness as a distinction *within* necessity. I think you could have an absolutely non-necessary fact for example. Indeed, I would say that ordinary empirical facts are of this sort. I am still working out my exact view and I hope this paper will help me to clarify it further. Thanks again.